# Sefer on bal tashchit

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, contemporary-halacha, bal-tashchit-waste

Is there any contemporary Sefer which covers the basics of hilchos bal tashchit, and practical cases of their relevancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a kuntres available on Hebrewbooks [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/53213) - authored by Rabbi Yosef Dovid Cohen

Comment: @Dov - sorry haven't seen anything else yet.